# How to bind a function to multiple ttk buttons to toggle between enabled/disabled?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Select Numbers")

def toggle(event):
    if event.widget.state(["disabled"]):
        event.widget.config(state="enabled")
    else:
        event.widget.config(state="disabled")

listOfBoxes = []
cnt = 1
for i in range(0, 8):
    listOfBoxes.append(ttk.Frame(root))
    for k in range(0, 10):
        tmp = ttk.Button(listOfBoxes[i], text=cnt)
        tmp.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
        tmp.bind("<Button-1>", toggle)
        cnt += 1
    listOfBoxes[i].pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

labelSelectedNumbers = ttk.Label(root, text="Selected Nubmers : ", font=("Helvetica", 10)).pack(fill=tk.X)

labelUserNumbers = ttk.Label(root, text=" some tmp text", font=("Helvetica", 10)).pack(fill=tk.X)

resetButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Reset").pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
submitButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Submit").pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

The toggle function does not work,it should disable the button when it's enabled and vice versa.
Could someone help me with this?

I even tried to manually disable a button based on the name but it doesn't work

Comment: If a button is disabled, you cannot click on it again to enable it back.

Comment: You can re-enable it. Let' s say we put this: tmp.bind("<Button-3>", toggle2)
When the button is disabled and you right click on it,it enables it again. The problem is that i want it to work with the left click,as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
This is the correct toggle function:

```
def toggle(event):
if event.widget.state(["!disabled"]):
    event.widget.config(state="enabled")
else:
    event.widget.config(state="disabled")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store buttons in a dict to be able to toggle them easily, like this :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Select Numbers")


def toggle(btn_id):
    if str(buttons[btn_id]["state"]) == "normal":
        buttons[btn_id]["state"] = "disabled"
    else:
        buttons[btn_id]["state"] = "normal"


listOfBoxes = []
cnt = 1
buttons = {}
for i in range(0, 8):
    listOfBoxes.append(ttk.Frame(root))
    for k in range(0, 10):
        tmp = ttk.Button(listOfBoxes[i], text=cnt,
                         command=lambda i=i, k=k: toggle(f'{i}-{k}'))
        tmp.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
        buttons[f'{i}-{k}'] = tmp
        cnt += 1
    listOfBoxes[i].pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

labelSelectedNumbers = ttk.Label(
    root, text="Selected Nubmers : ", font=("Helvetica", 10)).pack(fill=tk.X)

labelUserNumbers = ttk.Label(
    root, text=" some tmp text", font=("Helvetica", 10)).pack(fill=tk.X)

resetButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Reset").pack(
    fill=tk.X, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
submitButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Submit").pack(
    fill=tk.X, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```